# Bluetooth tethering breaks DNS routing

Tags: networking, bluetooth, tethering

Every time I use bluetooth to tether (via DUN) to my Samsung phone the DNS information is forced into other connections (WIFI/Ethernet).  Turning off the connection (and bluetooth) doesn't seem to fix it.  If I use the connection manager and try to set my wifi connection to automatic it always pulls in the old phone DNS addresses.  I can set the DNS manually which works when there's no proxy (only because I don't know the IP of the proxy to set the DNS to manually).

I can't figure out a way to auto configure DNS, the connection always ends up with the phone's DNS settings.

By the way, I had the same problem with a GSM USB dongle.  The only way I could fix it was to uninstall the GSM driver.  However with bluetooth tethering nothing shows up in the connection manager.

The IP will auto-configure, but the DNS never will.  Any thoughts?  (I've tried service networking restart, service network-manager restart, dhclient (-r and again without))  Rebooting, etc.

EDIT:  Using Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-48-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 19:45:16 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Is this perhaps a DNSMASQ issue?

Comment: Try to install package resolvconf. It is also use full to look at some log to see what happens. Try this command in a terminal 'tail -f /var/log/messages /var/log/syslog' and maybe add some other log files to look at. Try then to connect with Bluetooth.

Comment: @Anders I'll look at the syslog.  FYI -- connecting via bluetooth works fine, but any other connection (wifi/etc.) won't overwrite the DNS used during the bluetooth session unless I force a new DNS.

Comment: Have you the package `resolvconf` installed?